# Rounding issue in Sql Server 2008 R2 query

Tags: sql-server

can anybody help to solve following rounding problem. Thanks in advance

I have number: 3.1050 
Require Output: 3.10
but when I use ROUND(3.1050,2) I am getting result 3.11 hence I cant use ROUND over there..
Following are the some cases which help you solve my question

If value is : 3.1030
Require output : 3.10
If value is :3.1050
Require Output : 3.10
If value is : 3.1080
Require output : 3.11

Comment: I think you want ["bankers rounding"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding.aspx)/["round half to even"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) in T-SQL. The most efficient approach is to use the .NET `Math.Round` function as [CLR-function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter *I think you want bakers rounding in T-SQL.* Mmm... baker's rounding...

Comment: Yes, but I have to do this on SQL Server query not on .NET

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Banker's rounding is rounding towards even. The OPs' requirement is [Round Half Towards Zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_towards_zero)

Comment: depending of the expectet result for 3.1051 you could use Round(x-0.00000001,2) or Round(x-0.001,2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is the [Round Half Towards Zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_towards_zero) rounding method which SQL Server does not provide internally; SQL Server's ROUND() function always follows "Round away from zero" with an additional parameter for truncation instead of rounding.

Hence just write a user function which uses the Round() function around the edge case of last digit being 5 followed by zeroes:

```
Create Function dbo.RoundToZero(@Val Decimal(32,16), @Digits Int)
Returns Decimal(32,16)
AS
Begin
    Return Case When Abs(@Val - Round(@Val, @Digits, 1)) * Power(10, @Digits+1) = 5
                Then Round(@Val, @Digits, 1)
                Else Round(@Val, @Digits)
                End
End
```

Source: [SQL Server Rounding Methods](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-rounding-methods)